# "Failed to allocate memory" and "Expiring record" error after Kafka broker is down for 5+ mins and then rejoins the cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We're doing some testing on Kafka 1.1 brokers in AWS EC2.  Specifically, we're cleanly shutting brokers down for 5 mins or more, and then restarting them, while producing and consuming from the cluster all the time.  In theory, this should be relatively seamless to both producers and consumers.

However, we're getting these errors on the producer application when testing a broker being down for over 5 mins:

```
 ERROR - 2019-02-27 04:34:24.946 - message size [2494] 
       -Expiring 7 record(s) for topic2-0: 30033 ms has passed since last append
```

And then the first of many errors similar to this.

```
 ERROR - 2019-02-27 04:35:13.098; Topic [topic2], message size [2494] 
       -Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.
```

At that point, the long-running producers become non-responsive, and every producer request fails with that same `Failed to allocate memory`.  I tried to search online for similar issues, but all I could find is an old Kafka JIRA ticket that was resolved in 0.10.1.1, so it shouldn't apply for the newer 1.1 version we're using.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3651

We have attempted a lot of different scenarios, including changing the producer configuration back to Kafka defaults, to see if anything would help, but we always run into that problem whenever a broker comes back into the cluster after being down for 5 mins or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out how to fix this.  Posting it here in case it's useful to somebody else.

Our `producer.send` call had a callback defined that, in the event of an error, would attempt to re-send the message, using the same producer, to another topic.  This mechanism had been built so that, if the send call resulted in an error, we'd at least have the message stored in an error topic, where we could inspect the data and figure out what was going on.

This mechanism usually worked well, but whenever we lost a broker temporarily (had to take it down for maintenance/upgrades/etc), all of our applications would get stuck and eventually killed by the ELB.

From the official Javadoc for `KafkaProducer.send()`, I found this:

> Note that callbacks will generally execute in the I/O thread of the
>   producer and so should be reasonably fast or they will delay the
>   sending of messages from other threads. If you want to execute
>   blocking or computationally expensive callbacks it is recommended to
>   use your own Executor in the callback body to parallelize processing.

https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

The `producer.send` inside the callback qualifies as an expensive call, IMHO.  After doing some further debugging and profiling, it turns out all the XNIO threads were getting stuck while the callback `producer.send()` call was waiting on stale metadata, I guess, from when the broker rejoined the cluster.  This eventually caused the application to stop responding.

The fix in our case was to simply enqueue the error message in a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`, and have those messages be handled by a separate thread, whose only job was to `take` messages from the deque and try to re-send them.

After deploying this change to all our environments, the application has behaved perfectly throughout multiple broker restarts and outages.